# Reduce a table view's cell padding or margin

Tags: qt, qt4, tableview, qt4.6

I'm using a Table View.
I'd like to remove the cell padding (or margin) so I can squeeze more cells in less space.   How can this be achieved?
The cells size is set to 32 pixels on QT designer, if I set it smaller, the cells contents don't show and an ellipsis appears. (...)

[alt text http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/3484/tableviewpng.png](http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/3484/tableviewpng.png)

Comment: I used resizeRowsToContents() from QTableView and it also reduced the cell heights.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recommend you to use this code:

```
QTableView *tableView = new QTableView(this);

tableView->setModel(model_);

QHeaderView *verticalHeader = tableView->verticalHeader();
verticalHeader->setDefaultSectionSize(verticalHeader->fontMetrics().height()+2);

// or ...

QHeaderView *horizontalHeader = tableView->horizontalHeader();
horizontalHeader->setStretchLastSection(false);
horizontalHeader->resizeSection(/* your personal height */);
```

---

PS: Also I have noticed, that if in `tableView` too much rows or columns, for example about 20K rows or more, this functions `resizeSection()` may be too slow...

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it. This table is fixed at 16 x 128 cells, so I guess it won't have speed issues.